# How could I use IN close twice?

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

I have region table which has RegionID and Cordinates.

Region table :
RegionID
RegionPolygonCordinates

I have ListingRegion table which has RegionListingID, ListingID, and REgionID which is many to many table.

ListingRegion table :
RegionListingID
RegionID
ListingID

First I need to read the RegionIDs by location.
This is done as follows :

```
SELECT REGION_ID FROM region WHERE CONTAINS(REGION_POLYGON, point('45.512573', '-122.661276')
```

And then I need to get ListingIDs per each RegionID.

```
SELECT listings.* FROM listing_region,listings
WHERE  listings.LISTING_ID IN (SELECT listing_region.LIST_REGION_LISTING_ID IN (SELECT listing_region.LIST_REGION_REGION_ID IN (SELECT REGION_ID FROM region WHERE CONTAINS(REGION_POLYGON, point('45.512573', '-122.661276')))))
```

The above query does not work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please put sample data and expected result.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?  Error? Empty set?

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake.

The correct syntax would be as follows :

```
SELECT listings.* FROM listings
WHERE listings.LISTING_ID IN(SELECT listing_region.LIST_REGION_LISTING_ID FROM listing_region WHERE listing_region.LIST_REGION_REGION_ID IN (SELECT REGION_ID FROM region WHERE CONTAINS(REGION_POLYGON, point('45.512573', '-122.661276'))))
```